# drivers for my PC with ubuntu installed

Tags: wireless, drivers, nvidia, toshiba

I am still a beginner in using ubuntu , I have tried it a couple of times before on my old pc and actually  my experience was pretty dramatic,besides the fact that I really want to use ubuntu ,I have to use it for developing a project on a linux platform and specifically on ubuntu,it's demanded by my professor.

So,what I want to ask about because I'm afraid to lose my data or wipe out my HDD again or suffer from some problems concerning my wireless card or my graphics card.

1-is it okay if I went on using a virtual machine for development or will it be difficult, slow and has lots of drawbacks?

2-if I have no choice but to have a dual-boot pc ,I have a Toshiba Satellite L50-A668 with intel Graphics HD 4600 and Nvidia Geforce 740 M ,last time I wiped out my HDD,I really suffered until I got the proper drivers that made them work properly together
but that was on windows,however I didn't know to how to get them for ubuntu 14.04 LTS

how can I get versions of these drivers specifically for Ubuntu ?

this link includes all the specifications of my laptop :

http://www.toshibamea.com/ComputerProduct/4/Satellite_L50-A668/52942?pageid=4

Thanks in advance

Comment: "it's demanded by my professor" Me likes your professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it okay if I went on using a virtual machine for development or will it be difficult, slow and has lots of drawbacks?

For development you will not really notice the difference. A VM is all about tweaking it to your liking... too slow? add more RAM to the machine. Not enough space? Increase the machine.

But for development itself... unlikely you notice it.

Drawbacks. Nah. Only thing that annoyed me in the past was the constant switching between system and VM session. For all other purposes it worked very well.

> how can I get versions of these drivers specifically for Ubuntu ?

Linux uses generic drivers to set up your initial system. So IF the hardware is supported the driver will automatically install it for you. For your graphic card it can be useful to install the proprietary driver. This one will also be included in your system but as an option to install after the system is installed. See "dash","additional drivers". After a little search it will show all it can find based on your hardware (besides the graphics card it sometimes also list one for your wireless (Broadcom for instance)).

---

General advice: boot up one of the Ubuntu Live DVDs and have a look for yourself. In general: it it works during the Live session it will work after a normal install. If it does not you are 1 search on AU away from getting it working.